# const_iterator: nested class or friend class?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, const-iterator

I'm having some serious issues making this const_iterator for this `SparseGraph` class

The SparseGraph class:

For the intents and purposes of this post, a `SparseGraph` can be viewed as a list of lists (or vector of vectors) of edges (this is commonly known as an adjacency list). The `const_iterator` then iterates through each edge in the list of lists.

Consider:

```
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph
{
public:
    //...
    using EdgeList = std::vector<EdgeType>;
    using AdjacencyList = std::vector<EdgeList>;
    //...
private:
    //...
    AdjacencyList m_adj_list;
    //...
}
```

**Initial Attempt at const_iterator (nested class)**

```
//----SparseGraph
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph
{
public:
    class const_iterator; //nested
    //...
}

//----SparseGraph::const_iterator
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator
{
private:
    using NodeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::AdjacencyList::const_iterator;
    using EdgeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::EdgeList::const_iterator;

    //this is used to iterate through each edge list corresponding to each node
    NodeIterator m_node_it;

    //this is used to iterate through each edge in each edge list.
    EdgeIterator m_edge_it;

public:
    const_iterator(const NodeIterator& node_it, const EdgeIterator& edge_it)
        : m_node_it{node_it}, m_edge_it{edge_it} {}

    const_iterator& operator++(int)
    {
        //TODO
        return *this;
    }
    //...
```

As one may notice, the `operator++()` gives me the "non-static reference" error:

> error: invalid use of non-static data member 'SparseGraph::m_adj_list'

from:

```
//...
if(m_node_it == m_adj_list.end()) { //<--here,
    //loop back around to the beginning
    m_node_it = m_adj_list.begin(); //<--here,
}
m_edge_it = m_node_it.begin();//<--and here.
//...
```

---

**Initial Attempt at const_iterator (friend class)**

Now we have something along the lines of:

```
//----SparseGraph
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph
{
public:
    friend class const_iterator; //friend
    //as before...
}

//----SparseGraph::const_iterator-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class const_iterator
{
private:
    using NodeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::AdjacencyList::const_iterator;
    using EdgeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::EdgeList::const_iterator;

    const SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>& m_graph;
    NodeIterator m_node_it;
    EdgeIterator m_edge_it;

public:
    const_iterator(const SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>& graph,
                   const NodeIterator& node_it,
                   const EdgeIterator& edge_it)
        : m_graph{graph} {}
    //...
```

Which then gives me the errors

> error: 'const_iterator' does not name a type

for

```
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph
{
//...
public:
//...
    const_iterator begin() const;
//...
}
```

and

> error: need 'typename' before 'SparseGraph::const_iterator' because 'SparseGraph' is a dependent scope

for

```
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType> typename 
SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(*this, m_adj_list.begin(), m_adj_list.begin() >begin());
```

which then changes to

> error: no 'typename SparseGraph::const_iterator SparseGraph::begin() const' member function declared in class 'SparseGraph'

when I add that typename. I suspect this would be solved if I resolved the first error, however I don't know what the problem is there. Furthermore, the friend class is now polluting the scope of any translation unit in which it is included.

**My Current Code**

```
#ifndef SPARSE_GRAPH_H
#define SPARSE_GRAPH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum
{
    invalid_node_index=-1
};

template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph
{
public:
    class const_iterator;
    using Node = NodeType;
    using Edge = EdgeType;
    using NodeList = std::vector<Node>;
    using EdgeList = std::vector<Edge>;
    using AdjacencyList = std::vector<EdgeList>;

private:
    //...

    //Similarly to the NodeList, each node index is analogous
    //to its index in this list. Each element of this list contains
    //a sub-list of edges associated with a particular node.
    //For example, the list at index 3 will contain all edges associated
    //with the node with an index of 3. This is so we can have an O(1) lookup time.
    AdjacencyList m_adj_list;

    //...

public:
    SparseGraph() {}

    //...

    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;

    //...
};










//----SparseGraph::const_iterator-------------------------------------------
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class const_iterator
{
private:
    using NodeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::AdjacencyList::const_iterator;
    using EdgeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::EdgeList::const_iterator;

    NodeIterator m_node_it;
    EdgeIterator m_edge_it;
    const NodeIterator m_begin;
    const NodeIterator m_end;

public:
    const_iterator(NodeIterator node_it,
                   EdgeIterator edge_it,
                   NodeIterator begin,
                   NodeIterator end)
        : m_node_it{node_it}, m_edge_it{edge_it}, m_begin{begin}, m_end{end} {}

    const_iterator& operator++(int)
    {
        //are we at the end of a valid edge list?
        if(m_node_it != end && m_edge_it == m_node_it->end()) {
            //move to the next non-empty edge list or to the end of the adjacency list
            while(m_node_it != end && m_node_it->empty()) {
                m_node_it++;
            }
            if(m_node_it != end) {
                m_edge_it = m_node_it->begin();
            }
        }
        else {
            m_edge_it++;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    const_iterator& operator--(int)
    {
        //TODO
        return *this;
    }

    const typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::Edge& operator*() const
    {
        return *m_edge_it;
    }

    const typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::Edge* operator->() const
    {
        return &(*m_edge_it);
    }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator& other) const
    {
        return m_node_it == other.m_node_it &&
               m_edge_it == other.m_edge_it;
    }

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};










//----SPARSE_GRAPH----------------------------------------------------------

//----PUBLIC FUNCTIONS------------------------------------------------------

//----begin()
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(m_adj_list.begin(),
                          m_adj_list.begin()->begin(),
                          m_adj_list.begin(),
                          m_adj_list.back().end());
}

//----end()
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::end() const
{
    return const_iterator(m_adj_list.end(),
                          m_adj_list.end()->end(),
                          m_adj_list.begin(),
                          m_adj_list.back().end());
}

#endif // SPARSE_GRAPH_H
```

**My question is**, how should I be going about this? Should I use a nested const_iterator class or a friend const_iterator class, or perhaps, which way is standard? How should I implement the const_iterator to avoid these issues? Overall, I'm looking for a bidirectional const_iterator that will iterate through each Edge in an AdjacencyList (the list of lists) without allowing changes to the said AdjacencyList.

I've looked at other posts on this site relating to "const_pointer implementation", and even referred to Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language", yet nothing so far has given me insight into how to properly implement a const_iterator similar to this.

I am not at all comfortable with how to properly go about this so any help on anything (perhaps unrelated to the main question at hand) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the error?  Is it on the line with `return nullptr;`?  That wouldn't be a surprise.  Where do you define the implicit constructor `const_iterator(std::nullptr_t)`?

Comment: I posted this by mistake while it was still incomplete, give me a moment to tidy things up.

Comment: Please paste compiler messages verbatim, and indicate corresponding lines in posted sources.

Comment: typedef statement should be using EdgeList = std::vector<EdgeType>;

Comment: @Kapil You're right, except that I have an unshown "using Edge = EdgeType" above so it still works. I still changed it in this post for clarity.

Comment: You are using `class SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>const_iterator` instead of `class SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator`

Comment: @RSahu That was a problem during transcription. It doesn't actually affect the problem solution. Regardless, I've gone and fixed it.

Comment: Please don't use codeshare.io.  There's no "share" button and copy/paste doesn't work, so the code is visible but not accessible. You also have `#include "Graph_Enums.h"` which refers to a non-existing file. I had to vote for closing your question because it fails to provide code in a reasonable form. According to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.* See also [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. I've changed my post so that I explicitly stated my question and the desired behavior at the bottom of the post and moved the source code from codeshare to dropbox and provided a public link. I've also resolved the matter involving "Graph_Enums.h". All the code relating to my problem specifically is in the question. The source code link at the bottom is simply for those looking for greater detail.

Comment: @n.m Unless there are other issues with what I have here, I politely request that I have this post taken off hold.

Comment: Formally the question remains off topic as, I repeat the guideline, *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself* (not as a link to an external resource). I will vote to reopen it though, I hope you will just transfer the code from dropbox to the question.

Comment: There is a massive amount of problems with the code. It is easy to get it to compile by turning a friend class to a nested class (there's no good reason *not* to use a nested class). However your code doesn't instantiate any templates. When you try that, real problems begin...

Comment: @n.m. I've added all the required code as requested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144594/discussion-between-n-m-and-aldenb).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get it to compile by turning a friend class to a nested class (there's no good reason not to use a nested class). However your code doesn't instantiate any templates. When you try that, real problems begin.

Here's the diffs you need to apply:

```
friend class const_iterator;                                      (ca. line 26) ===> 

       class const_iterator;

class const_iterator                                              (ca. line 98) ===> 

        template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>                               
        class SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator

const_iterator SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::begin() const     (ca. line 301) ===>

        typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator
        SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::begin() const

const_iterator SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::end() const       (ca. line 308) ===>

        typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator
        SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::end() const
```

However your code doesn't instantiate any templates. When you try to create a const_iterator and increment it, the real problem shows up. Namely, your edge list, vertex list, and adjacency list types and their iterators, const iterators and const_iterators are all mixed up in one big salad bowl. They need to be carefully separated and cleaned up.

There is also no copy/move ctor for the const_iterator class, and possibly other minor problems.

Comment: @AldenB Sorry I must have written this before the massive edit. Will revise.

Comment: @AldenB Answer updated and reinstated. We can discuss the problems in the chat if you want.

Comment: Does this apply to my current code stated in the question?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. E.g. both node_iterator and edge_iterator typedefed to be an adjacency_list::iterator, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Oops! that was an error made when transcribing the code. I'll fix that right away!

Comment: Oh if it has changed compared to the dropbox version I need to check my changes again. I'm on mobile right now, please wait a few hours.

Comment: Yes, the dropbox version is no longer viable. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144597/discussion-between-aldenb-and-n-m).

Answer (score 0):

Your original

> error: invalid use of non-static data member 'SparseGraph::m_adj_list'

indicates there isn't a `SparseGraph` in scope to get `m_adj_list.begin()`. You don't need to call that, just store SparseGraph::m_adj_list's begin and end in your const_iterator

```
template <typename NodeType, typename EdgeType>
class SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::const_iterator
{
private:
    using NodeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::AdjacencyList::const_iterator;
    using EdgeIterator = typename SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType>::AdjacencyList::const_iterator;

    const_iterator(NodeIterator node_it, EdgeIterator edge_it, NodeIterator adjacent_begin, NodeIterator adjacent_end) : m_node_it{node_it}, m_edge_it{edge_it}, m_adjacent_begin{adjacent_begin}, m_adjacent_end{adjacent_end} {}

    const NodeIterator m_adjacent_begin;
    const NodeIterator m_adjacent_end;
    NodeIterator m_node_it;
    EdgeIterator m_edge_it;

    const_iterator& operator++(int)
    {
        //are we at the end of this edge list?
        if(m_edge_it == m_node_it->end()) {
            //move to the next node's edge list.
            m_node_it++;
            //are we past the last node's edge list?
            if(m_node_it == m_adjacent_end) {
                //loop back around to the beginning
                m_node_it = m_adjacent_begin;
            }
            m_edge_it = m_node_it.begin();
        }
        else {
            m_edge_it++;
        }
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually quite helpful. Is this code optimal/ideal?

Comment: The `operator++` is just matching your behaviour. I'd suggest changing the ifs to whiles, so that you skip empty edges rather than dereferencing their ends. I'm also wary of the `m_node_it = m_adjacent_begin`, instead I would just stop. Otherwise `operator==` gets more complex than `return (m_node_it == other.m_node_it) && (m_edge_it == other.m_edge_it)`

Comment: That is, I would expect `SparseGraph::end` to be `{ return const_iterator(m_adj_list.end(), m_adj_list.back().end(), m_adj_list.begin(), m_adj_list.end()); }` and not `{ return const_iterator(m_adj_list.begin(), m_adj_list.front().begin(), m_adj_list.begin(), m_adj_list.end()); }`